# DRF oneToOneField Create Serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

trying to do some nested model creation with drf/create serizlizer.

what i'm trying to serialize is 'TradePost' model, which has post, and ProductItem in it.

i already have 'ProductItemSerializer', and 'PostSerializer' by using this.. how can i serialize them?? with creation? not by telling existing record with pk value.

models.py

```
class ProductItem(models.Model):
    baseProduct = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='baseProduct')

    seller = models.ForeignKey(User)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    isOrderClosed = models.BooleanField()
    isTradeCompleted = models.BooleanField()


    def __str__(self):
        return '[seller = '+self.seller.username+']' + '[product = '+(str)(self.baseProduct)+']' + '[id = '+(str)(self.id)+']'




class TradePost(models.Model):

    basePost = models.OneToOneField(Post)

    baseProductItem = models.OneToOneField(ProductItem)

    def __str__(self):
        return '[post = ' + (str)(self.basePost) + ']' + '[product = ' + (str)(self.baseProductItem) + ']' + '[id = ' + (str)(self.id) + ']'
```

in serialziers.py

```
class ProductItemCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductItem
        fields = ('baseProduct', 'price')



#???
class TradePostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TradePost
        fields = ('basePost', 'baseProductItem',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post =
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the [writable nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers), you can try something like this:

```
class TradePostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    basePost = PostCreateSerializer()
    baseProductItem = ProductItemCreateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TradePost
        fields = ('basePost', 'baseProductItem',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # pop out the dict to create post and item, depend on whether you want to create post or not
        post = validated_data.get('basePost')
        product = validated_data.get('baseProductItem')
        # create post first
        trade_post = None
        post_obj = Post.objects.create(**post)
        if post_obj:
            # create product item
            prod_item = ProductItem.objects.create(basePost=post_obj, **product)
            trade_post = TradePost.objects.create(baseProduct=prod_item, **validated_data)
        return trade_post
```

For python, please follow naming convention and use `lower_case_with_underscores` like `base_product`, `base_post`, it will be much easier to read

Answer (score -1):

You can use serializers to represent field, For eg,

```
class TradePostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    basePost = PostSerializer()
    baseProductItem = ProductItemSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = TradePost
        fields = ('basePost', 'baseProductItem',)
```

Reference:

[DRF Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)

If you're looking for writable nested serializers

[Writable nested serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: i mean in that way, it needs pk value of which is already created record.
or? am i miss understanding?

Comment: getting this

{
    "basePost": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."
    ],
    "baseProductItem": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."
    ]
}